Custom connectionString builder cause XConnect Services/Job timed out
I'm encountering an issue with the XConnect Collection Search - IndexWorker service, which is unable to start after implementing a custom connection string builder. The error message is:
Error 1053: The service did not respond the start or control request in a timely fashion.
When I try to start the service, it doesn't produce any logs except for my custom log to track the process of my custom code:
12/2/2024 4:47:16 PM [Info] Get AWS Secret: secretmanager_sitecore_LocalSqlServer. Profile:  Region: ap-southeast-1
12/2/2024 4:47:17 PM [Warning] Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret.
12/2/2024 4:47:17 PM [Info] Config secretmanager_sitecore_LocalSqlServer is not found
12/2/2024 4:47:17 PM [Info] Get AWS Secret: secretmanager_sitecore_collection. Profile:  Region: ap-southeast-1
12/2/2024 4:47:18 PM [Info] Get config [Database] from AWS Secret: {redacted}
12/2/2024 4:47:18 PM [Info] Get AWS Secret: secretmanager_sitecore_solrCore. Profile:  Region: ap-southeast-1
12/2/2024 4:47:18 PM [Warning] Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret.
12/2/2024 4:47:18 PM [Info] Config secretmanager_sitecore_solrCore is not found
12/2/2024 4:47:21 PM [Info] Get AWS Secret: secretmanager_sitecore_LocalSqlServer. Profile:  Region: ap-southeast-1
12/2/2024 4:47:23 PM [Warning] Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret.
12/2/2024 4:47:23 PM [Info] Config secretmanager_sitecore_LocalSqlServer is not found
12/2/2024 4:47:23 PM [Info] Get AWS Secret: secretmanager_sitecore_collection. Profile:  Region: ap-southeast-1
12/2/2024 4:47:24 PM [Info] Get config [Database] from AWS Secret: {redacted}
12/2/2024 4:47:24 PM [Info] Get AWS Secret: secretmanager_sitecore_solrCore. Profile:  Region: ap-southeast-1
12/2/2024 4:47:24 PM [Warning] Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret.
12/2/2024 4:47:24 PM [Info] Config secretmanager_sitecore_solrCore is not found

This issue occurred in my QA environment, but when I tried to replicate it on my local machine, it behaved differently.
Things that I've tried:

I tried to execute the Sitecore.XConnectSearchIndexer.exe directly but didn't see any issue
Increased the service timeout to 30 seconds (previously it was 5 seconds)

I appreciate any insights or suggestions regarding this issue. Thanks in advance!
Update-1
This is my custom code for the custom connectionString builder
using Amazon.SecretsManager;
using Amazon.SecretsManager.Model;
using Project.Base.Aws.Models.Response;
using Project.Base.Aws.Utils;
using Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Project.Base.Aws.SecretManager
{
    public class ConnectionStringBuilder : KeyValueConfigBuilder
    {
        public override ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetAllValues(string prefix)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string GetValue(string key)
        {
            try
            {
                IAmazonSecretsManager client = new AmazonSecretsManagerClient(new AmazonSecretsManagerConfig()
                {
                    ReadWriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
                });

                XConnectLogUtils.Log(LogNotificationLevel.Info ,$"Get AWS Secret: {key}. Profile: {client.Config.Profile} Region: {client.Config.RegionEndpoint.SystemName}");
                ScLogUtils.Info(this, message:$"Get AWS Secret: {key}. Profile: {client.Config.Profile} Region: {client.Config.RegionEndpoint.SystemName}");

                string awsSecret = _GetAwsSecrets(client, key);

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(awsSecret))
                {
                    XConnectLogUtils.Log(LogNotificationLevel.Info, $"Config {key} is not found");
                    ScLogUtils.Info(this, message: $"Config {key} is not found");
                    return null;
                }

                AwsSecretManagerDbResponse awsDbSecretModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AwsSecretManagerDbResponse>(awsSecret);

                if (awsDbSecretModel == null)
                {
                    AwsSecretManagerKeyValueResponse awsKeyvalueSecretModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AwsSecretManagerKeyValueResponse>(awsSecret);

                    if (awsKeyvalueSecretModel == null)
                    {
                        XConnectLogUtils.Log(LogNotificationLevel.Info, $"Config {key} cannot be parsed.");
                        ScLogUtils.Info(this, message:$"Config {key} cannot be parsed.");
                        return null;
                    }

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(awsKeyvalueSecretModel.Value))
                    {
                        XConnectLogUtils.Log(LogNotificationLevel.Info, $"Config {key} is empty. Returning empty as result");
                        ScLogUtils.Info(this, message:$"Config {key} is empty. Returning empty as result");
                        return string.Empty;
                    }

                    XConnectLogUtils.Log(LogNotificationLevel.Info, $"Get config [KeyValue] from AWS Secret: {{redacted}}");
                    ScLogUtils.Info(this, message:$"Get config [KeyValue] from AWS Secret: {{redacted}}");
                    ScLogUtils.Debug(this, message: $"Get config [KeyValue] from AWS Secret: {_CensorPassword(awsKeyvalueSecretModel.Value, awsKeyvalueSecretModel.Value)}");
                    return awsKeyvalueSecretModel.Value;
                }

                var config = string.Empty;

                if (awsDbSecretModel.Port == null || !awsDbSecretModel.UsePort)
                {
                    config = $"Data Source={awsDbSecretModel.Host};";
                }
                else
                {
                    config = $"Data Source={awsDbSecretModel.Host},{awsDbSecretModel.Port};";
                }

                config = config + $"Initial Catalog={awsDbSecretModel.DatabaseName};" +
                    $"User Id={awsDbSecretModel.Username};" +
                    $"Password={awsDbSecretModel.Password};";

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(awsDbSecretModel.Metadata))
                {
                    XConnectLogUtils.Log(LogNotificationLevel.Info, $"Get config [Database] from AWS Secret: {{redacted}}");
                    ScLogUtils.Info(this, message:$"Get config [Database] from AWS Secret: {{redacted}}");
                    ScLogUtils.Debug(this, message: $"Get config [Database] from AWS Secret: {_CensorPassword(config,awsDbSecretModel.Password)}");
                    return config;
                }

                var metaDataConfig = $"metadata={awsDbSecretModel.Metadata};" +
                    $"provider={awsDbSecretModel.Provider};" +
                    $"provider connection string=\"{config}MultipleActiveResultSets={awsDbSecretModel.MultipleActiveResultSets};App={awsDbSecretModel.App}\";";

                XConnectLogUtils.Log(LogNotificationLevel.Info, $"Get config [Database-Metadata] from AWS Secret: {{redacted}}");
                ScLogUtils.Info(this, message: $"Get config [Database-Metadata] from AWS Secret: {{redacted}}");
                ScLogUtils.Debug(this, message: $"Get config [Database-Metadata] from AWS Secret: {_CensorPassword(metaDataConfig, awsDbSecretModel.Password)}");
                return metaDataConfig;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                XConnectLogUtils.Log(LogNotificationLevel.Error, $"Failed to get value for: {key}. {ex.Message} \n {ex.StackTrace}");
                ScLogUtils.Error(this, message:$"Failed to get value for: {key}");
                ScLogUtils.Error(this, ex);
            }

            return null;
        }

        // Get AWS Secret from AWS
        private string _GetAwsSecrets(IAmazonSecretsManager client, string key)
        {
            try
            {
                GetSecretValueRequest request = new GetSecretValueRequest
                {
                    SecretId = key
                };

                GetSecretValueResponse response;
                response = client.GetSecretValue(request);

                return response.SecretString;
            } catch(ResourceNotFoundException ex)
            {
                XConnectLogUtils.Log(LogNotificationLevel.Warning, $"{ex.Message}");
                ScLogUtils.Warn(this, ex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                XConnectLogUtils.Log(LogNotificationLevel.Error, $"{ex.Message} \n {ex.StackTrace}");
                ScLogUtils.Error(this, ex);
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }

        private string _CensorPassword(string connectionString, string password)
        {
            return connectionString.Replace(password, new string('*', password.Length));
        }
    }
}


Please provide any custom code. A good starting point would be why it is unable to access/locate the secrets.

the code able to access/locate the secret, it's in the log 12/2/2024 4:47:18 PM [Info] Get config [Database] from AWS Secret: {redacted}. I will add my custom code nonetheless.
